# Web Farm Servers and Tasks

Tags: kentico

I am hosting a Kentico 9 site on Azure where it is hosted across two servers.  Those servers change periodically through Azure.  I just noticed that there are like 25 different servers in my Web Farm > Servers configuration; all but two are in a Not Responding state, since they are old servers that are no longer a part of the deployment.  How can I make sure that Kentico is cleaning these servers up as well as their tasks?  I have hundreds of thousands of tasks in the Web Farm > Tasks section due to all of these web farm servers.  Any idea about the best way to keep this area clean?

Answer (score 2):

In version 9 there were issues with web farm servers (and their child tasks) not cleaning up properly or automatically.  So best to apply either the latest hotfix OR upgrade to a supported version of Kentico.

If neither of those options are available to you, then you will want to run some queries to clean those servers and tasks up because they most likely won't delete on their own.

Answer (score 1):

The better option would be upgrade to V10 or later version of Kentico where automatic web farm was introduced for the purpose of Azure web farm or scale out option.